# C++ Equivalent of Tidy

Tags: c++

Is there an equivalent to tidy for HTML code for C++? I have searched on the internet, but I find nothing but C++ wrappers for tidy, etc... I think the keyword tidy is what has me hung up.

I am basically looking for something to take code written by two people, and clean it up to a standardized style. Does such an app exist?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)

> is a source code indenter, formatter,
>   and beautifier for the C, C++, C#  and
>   Java programming languages.

[GC Great Code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcgreatcode/)

> is a well known C/C++ source code
>   beautifier.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I find an answer to my own question moments later. What luck, I probably spent an hour searching earlier.

Should anyone be looking for the same thing, check out Uncrustify at http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The 'remove {} on single statement after if, for, etc..' is a no-go for me. That makes maintenance risky.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio then you could take a look at [StyleManager](http://www.profactor.co.uk/stylemanager.php)*.  It's a VS add-in that makes it easy to set up formatting styles and apply them to code whenever you need to.  It's a popular choice with VS users, and in particular was used by the DirectX SDK team to tidy up their sample code.

*Huge disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of this software, so apologies for the shameless plug!

Answer (score 0):

You can tidy your code online, with this website:

- https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier
- https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier